# List for contour region with a function of three variables

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a function `f[t,x,y]= x^2 y^2 t^(-2) Exp[(y/t)]^-1` and I want a data list of the variables **x vs. y** that satisfy `f[t,x,y]>1`, so that I can draw a boundary line that distinguishes between those two regions (`f[t,x,y]>1` and `f[t,x,y]<1`). The first variable **t** can be chosen arbitrarily. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_, x_, y_] = x^2 y^2 t^(-2) Exp[(y/t)]^-1;
t = 1;
ContourPlot[f[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> {1}, 
 ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Red}, 
 ContourShading -> {LightGreen, LightBlue}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As `t` can be chosen arbitrarily, we set it simply to one. Then the function simplifies to:

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2 y^2  Exp[(y)]^-1
```

The boundary between f>1 and f<1 can be obtained by:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 0}]
```

[image: output of contourplot: a function with a downward pointing cusp]

Or using `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[
  {f[x, y] < 1, f[x, y] == 1, f[x, y] > 1},
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -5, 0}, MaxRecursion -> 7
]
```

[image: ![similar plot, but colorized]

Comment: If I have to vary ```t``` then  how should I do it?

Comment: Simply introduce t again as a parameter.

Comment: But a function with three variables in either ```ContourPlot``` or ```RegionPlot``` do't work.

Comment: I said "as parameter", not as argument. To plot t must have a numerical value that you can insert in the definition of f.

Comment: I tried to generate random numbers for each vairables and then solved the function. Then I used ```ListContourPlot``` with ```RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z > 1]```. I does look a bit somthing I wanted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
With[
{
     reg=ImplicitRegion[x^2 y^2 t^(-2) Exp[(y/t)]^-1<1,{x,y,t}]
}
,RegionPlot3D[reg]
]
```

[image]